# Use the GL-AR300M as an Network Emulator

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, openwrt, bridging

I am trying to configure the GL-AR300M as a network emulator.

**The Setup**: I'm using a MacBook with MacOS and an GL iNet 300m mini smart router. I've connected the mini router via LAN to my Mac and changed the IP adress of the Mac's LAN interface to 192.168.8.2. This change is important because I've configured (via ssh and vi /etc/config/network) the router like this: All configs except 'loopback' and 'global' have been deleted and I inserted the following:

```
config interface 'lan'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'
    option hostname 'GL-AR300M-56a'
    option ipaddr '192.168.8.1'
    option ifname 'eth0 eth1'
    option gateway '192.168.8.2'
    option delegate '0'
    list dns '9.9.9.9'
```

I can open the dashboard of the router via 192.168.1.

Now I am trying to download some  plug-ins. For this the Router needs an active internet connection. I've configured the interface (from which the router is connected to my Macbook) as a shared connection with Wi-Fi (my Mac is connected via Wi-Fi with the internet).

But my Mac and router has no internet.

**Question**:

- Should I configure the routes of the packages?
- How do I do this?
- How do I get an internet connection on the router?

Comment: Welcome. Please note that we allow only one question per post. It appears you have two different questions, and one is clearly more important than the other: how to get internet to the router. I took the liberty of correcting spelling and formatting issues with your question. Please EDIT your question further to focus only one the primary question. Once that has been solved, you can post another question about configuring your plugins, if that is still an issue by then.